# SQL Excel Export

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have the following SQL which works fine on my instance of SQL Server (2012), I have tested this on two client machines who are also both running this version and they receive the error below

Mine

```
   DECLARE @FileName varchar(50),
   @bcpCommand varchar(8000)

   SET @bcpCommand  = 'bcp northwind.dbo.customers out c:\Temp\Testing.xls -T -r\n -c -t\t'
   PRINT @bcpCommand
   EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

Error
Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.

Difference
The only difference between mine and the client is that instead of a trusted connection -T, I specify the username and password

```
  SET @bcpCommand  = 'bcp Production.dbo.Cashbook out C:\Temp\Testing.xls -usa -ppassword -r\n -c -t\t -s@@SERVERNAME'
```

Comment: What happens when you run the problem code on your machine?

Comment: I managed to solve it using the following

SET @bcpCommand  = 'bcp [Gem].dbo.Cashbook out "C:\Temp\Testing.csv" -Usa -Ppassword -STECH-PC\SQLEXPRESS -r\n -w'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try changing the case of the `-u` to `-U` and of the `-p` to `-P`.  I was reading that it is case sensitive.

Comment: Unfortunately still the same